# Java regex pattern replacing space followed by special character

Tags: java, regex

I have below 2 strings

```
1. Economy / Coach
2. First Class
```

I want regex pattern in such a way,

Conditions :

1. If the space is followed by special character(/),  I need to remove the space with "". (Example : Economy / Coach to Economy/Coach )
2. If the space is not followed by any special character, then the string should be as it is. (Example: First Class to First class)

Expected output:

```
1. Economy/Coach
2. First class
```

Can anybody please help me to write this regex pattern?
Thanks in advance

Comment: By special character, you mean only  `/` _(slash)_ or there is others (a collection)?

Comment: The problem will be that also the space AFTER the "special character" should be removed. So, is the `.` also a special character?

Comment: Thank you . Working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is tu use [String#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method, but you have to store it explicitely into the variable because strings are immutable. The `replaceAll` method will give you a new instance and will not affect the original string.

Example :

```
String str = "Economy / Coach";
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+/\\s+", "/");
```

Note that the pattern "\\s+" will capture each sequence of spaces (tabulations, spaces etc..).

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace occurrences of `" / "` with `"/"`:

```
String replaced = string.replace(" / ", "/");
```

Note that this doesn't use regex (directly; it does internally, but that's just an implementation detail).

Comment: This is not a dynamic answer though, If it contains 2 spaces on both the side then it will not worked.

Comment: @KunjanShah that's not what the question asks: "If *the space* is followed by special character...".

Comment: This misunderstanding is why at least half of the battle is a clear definition of what it is you are trying to accomplish.  For example: _"for each slash that is present, remove any spaces on either side of it"_

Answer (score -1):

First Check with "/" is in the String or not.
If it is in that, then remove the WhiteSpaces.

```
   if(testString.contains("/")){
        str1 = testString.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    }
```

Comment: This replaces *all* spaces in the string, wherever they are.

Comment: ...which would result in `1.Economy/Coach` - i guess that's not what's wanted